# Format the value of a datetime-local input into a user-locale string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

If I use a `<input type="datetime-local" />` in a compatible browser (e.g. Chrome), the value I get from this input is an ISO timestamp without timezone, such as `2015-01-31T23:50`

Then I want to format this timestamp according to the user's locale. For example, as I'm in France (UTC+1), I want to get : `31/01/2015 23:50`

When I use the following code, the timestamp is interpreted as UTC and I get this date : `1/2/2015 00:50 UTC+1`

```
new Date(timestamp).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, {
  year: "numeric", month: "numeric", day: "numeric", 
  hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", 
  timeZoneName: "short" 
})
```

I could read the timezone offset using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`, turn it into a string ISO timezone and then append it to the timestamp, but it seems rather complex to me.

What would be a simpler, **pure js or jquery** (no other libs) solution to format the timestamp the way I want ?

Answer (score 2):

You should bypass all javascript date formating functions to the very last moment.

In your case the format `1/01/2015 23:50` matches the es-ES or en-GB culture date format so you can use the function toLocaleString to obtain the desired format in just one call ;).

The problem is that if you convert your date directly with `new Date()` it will interpret as ISO-8601 format this will make things a little harder so you should instantiate with a string to be treated as a local date.

```
    var withOffset = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-GB');
    console.log(withOffset);

    var withoutOffset= new Date(timestamp.replace('T', ' ')).toLocaleString('en-GB');
    console.log(withoutOffset);
```

The second version will convert `2015-01-31T23:50` to `2015-01-31 23:50` and this will be interpreted as `Sat Jan 31 2015 23:50:00 GMT+0100` and then toLocaleString convert it to your desired format.

Please note that this might not work consistently across browsers because you are not using an standard format to convert the string to date(I only tested it in Chrome)

> The ECMAScript specification states: If the String does not conform to the standard format the function may fall back to any implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing algorithm.

Comment: The `2015-01-31 23:50` timestamp does not parse in FF/Safari and `2015-01-31T23:50` is not interpreted the same way as shows this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gfouquet/d0L8vnv8/ . I'd rather use a portable solution

Comment: I think you should use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It's a very powerfull library for parsing and converting dates. The solution I provided it's not supposed to be cross-browser because as I posted before is not a standard format. If you want to use the standard format then you should use the offset correction. Perhaps you could set the string as an standard format and that should work cross browser.